# Will SSDT-BI work with SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Can some one tell me whether the SSIS packages developed in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 works in 2008r2 server or not ???

If yes, did any other software needs to be installed in the 2008r2 server?

Deployment is not any concern here. I just want to run the packages in 2008r2 server via sql agent job

Please help.

Comment: I browsed in the internet found the below link. But still this is not clear. Someone please suggest me who came up with this situation.
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101335/will-ssdt-bi-work-with-sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Backwards compatibility is not an option. A package built in 2014 will not run on 2012. A 2012 package will not run on 2008 and a 2008 package will not run on 2005.

However, forward compatibility does exist so a 2005 package will run on 2008. 2008 will run on 2012, 2012 on 2014.

While I don't think this is your scenario, if you have the 2012/2014 SSIS packages deployed to a 2012/2014 server, you could run them from the 2008 server's SQL Agent task. It'd just be a matter of scripting the `catalog.create_execution` and `catalog.start_execution` [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878160.aspx)

Having that SQL Script, add a job step task of SQL and point the context over to your 2012/2014 server.

Comment: I have visual studio 2013. My plan is to develop the package in VS2013 and deploy the package to the file system and schedule it to run via sql agent.(2008r2 server).
Seems like this will never work.

Comment: I just tested this and getting the below error. Now i'm sure, this won't work.


Source: 
Description: The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.
End Error
Error: 2009-06-18 11:22:05.33
Code: 0xC0016020
Source: 
Description: Package migration from version 3 to version 2 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than current version number.".

Answer (score 2):

MSDN at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx contains an overview of all the supported VS/SQLServer version combinations.

Basically, for SQLServer2008R2 SSIS development you will need BIDS (from the SQLServer installation).

The VS2012/VS2013 tools support only SQLServer2012/2014 SSIS development.

For VS2015, the Februari preview release of the SSDT-BI tools is intended to support multi-targetting SSIS package development (but only SQLServer2012-2016, no 2008R2), see also in the comments at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2015/12/16/sql-server-data-tools-preview-update-for-december-2015.aspx

Note there is also something called BIML which is able to generate SSIS packages for different versions of SQLServer (incl 2008R2) from the same source code, so you could possibly use VS2012/VS2013 with BIDSHelper and then as a last step maybe generate packages for SQLServer2008R2.

Comment: So if I am trying to build a package and deploy to SQL Server 2012 I have to use Visual Studio 2012 - except I can't find a download for that version - it is no longer available unless I have a MSDN Subscription.  What other way can I create and deploy SSIS packages for SQL Server 2012?  this page on the SSDT Tools  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674925.aspx state "Please note that SSIS designer support for SSIS 2012 and 2014 is not yet included in this update."

Comment: There is a previous versies download at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx also the most recent April SSDTBI preview for VS2015 has support for SSIS2012, but as said it is currently still a preview at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt429383

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to get it deployed with the SSDTBI preview!